# Installation of Office 365 for Mac is freezing at "Running Package Scripts" (Sierra)

Tags: macos, ms-office, microsoft

I just downloaded `Office 365 for Mac`, and tried to install it in `macOS Sierra 10.12.5`. The installation froze when `Running Package Scripts`.

It is a common problem. I followed [this answer](https://discussions.apple.com/message/22262324#message22262324) and launched `Disk Utility`, but it seems that there is no `repair disk permission` in Sierra.

Then, I found [the answer of dianeoforegon here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_other-mso_mac/office-2011-install-is-stuck-on-running-package/18e45462-36fa-47ff-8fe9-6378a26f6100). I did pay attention to close all browsers and applications (except `Finder`) before launching the installer. Clicking on `Shift` did not help either.

It is really annoying. Does anyone have a solution? Otherwise, how could I clean what I have installed completely?

**Edit 1:** I chatted to Microsoft support yesterday, and they let me create a new user account on my Mac, and install Office 365 under that account. I tried, the installation was freezing at the same place.

**Edit 2:** I chatted to another Microsoft support agent, he suggested me to remove the Office before installing, I then removed them in `Applications`, there was no `Library/Containers` or `Library/Group Containers` (I guess it is because the installation was not completed). And the re-installation still failed at the same place.

Additionally, I have to use VPN to connect to the internet, some sites still don't work well. Is this an issue? Does `Running Package Scripts` require some special Internet connection?

Comment: Is this a totally fresh installation (i.e. no prior installation of Office 365)? If so, as far as you can tell, has anything been installed at all?

Comment: There was for example Microsoft Excel previously installed, and I don't remember other applications. I don't know how to check if anything new has been installed. If I look at the `Date Modified` in `Applications`, I don't see any `Microsoft xxxxx` whose `Date Modified` is yesterday.

Answer (score 1):

Turn off virus protection. As soon as I did that the installer completed the task.

Comment: wow super, disabling virus protection worked!

Comment: That seems to have worked for me too, though I have to admit it's not a good feeling to have to disable AV to install an application... Thanks for the tip though. :)

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me: Go to Acitivity Monitor and quit "installer". This prompts the last bit of installation.

https://discussions.apple.com/message/32522381#message32522381

Comment: This is only thing that worked for me.  First I tried Quit, then Force Quit of the "Installer" process.  Now I can finally open and save docx files in Word or my mac.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I would try is booting into Safe Mode and installing Office 365 from there. This is what I *think* the answer of dianoforegon you referred to was trying to achieve, but her steps weren't the best way to go. Instead, try the following:

1. Fully shut down your Mac
2. Restart your Mac
3. Immediately press the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key and **keep it down**
4. Let go of the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key when you see the login window (NOTE: If you have FileVault enabled you may need to log in twice. Also, booting into Safe Mode can take quite a while in some cases.)
5. Now try installing Office 365 again from your download
6. If it doesn't work, take a note of any errors etc you get
7. Exit Safe Mode by restarting your Mac as normal

Let me know if this doesn't work and any error you get.

Comment: Thank you... The booting into Safe Mode took 10 minutes, then I could finally launch the installer. The installation was freezing at the same place (running package scripts)...

Comment: Same. Does not help at all to get past the 50% problem.